# How to pass 2 arguments to a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I am working with HTML and Javascript.
I want to pass 2 arguments to the **signUp** function. I do not know where to put the **comma** between two arguments. Please help me!
Below is my code:

```
cellAction.outerHTML = "<input type='button' value='Approve' class='approve' onclick='signUp(  \""+childData.email+"\"+\""+,childKey+"\"  )'></td>";
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You do not need any `+` and quotes:

```
cellAction.outerHTML = "<input type='button' value='Approve' class='approve' onclick='signUp(childData.email, childKey)'></td>";
```

**Demo:**

```js
var childData = {email: 'aa@xy.com'};
var childKey = 'k123';
var cellAction = document.getElementById('cellAction');
cellAction.outerHTML = "<input type='button' value='Approve' class='approve' onclick='signUp(childData.email, childKey)'></td>";

function signUp(email, key){
  console.log(email + " :: " + key);
}
```

```html
<div id="cellAction"></div>
```

Comment: I am sorry, but it doesn't work for me. 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: childData is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (test.html:1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use template literals

```
cellAction.outerHTML = `<input type='button'
                               value='Approve'
                               class='approve' 
                               onclick='signUp(${childData.email},${childKey})'>
                        </td>`;
```